# Android onDestroy incorrect behaviour while removing app from recent list

Tags: android, ondestroy

I faced strange behaviour of onDestroy function.
I'm trying to save few parametrs inside onDestroy via SharedPreference object. Here is the code.

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy() - ");
    // так же сохраняем статус приложение (закрыто) в shared preperence
    // для того чтобы из ресивера пушей можно было узнать статус приложения
    try{
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy() - A");
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = preferences.edit();
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy() - C");
        ed.putString(packageName, statusClosed);
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy() - D");
        ed.commit();
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy() - E");
        //Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy() - Sharedpref save OK. Arg = " + getPackageName() + " Val = " + getString(R.string.core_pushns_status_closed));
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy() - Sharedpref save error.");
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy2()");
}
```

When I close app using hardware back button - everything is ok.
When I close app using menu button function ed.commit() crashes.
Any ideas? 
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Can you put your logs please ?

Comment: You're not calling super.onDestroy()

Comment: I called super.onDestoy() but just forgot to past it here. Sorry

Comment: Another point is that you usually want to save these things in onStop, since onDestroy() may not be called.

Comment: I need to save my parametr exactly in onDestroy because in this case application is closed. onPause and onStop methods means that app not closed.